# I have to count the all the possible pair from left to right in array.How I can do it effectively?

Tags: java, algorithm

//Below is my implementation how I improve that?

```
    int[] numbers = { 1, 5, 23, 2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 8, 12, 3 };
    int count = 0;
    int length = numbers.length;


    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        for(int j= i+1;j<length; j++ ){
            if(j!=i && numbers[i]==numbers[j]){
                count+=1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think it needs improvement? Does it not work? If it does and you want to peer review post your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could remove `j!=i`. It does nothing

Comment: What is the "correct" answer in this case? is it 4?

Comment: its complexity is O(n2) so how i cam improve my solution

Comment: input :(1,1,1,1)  
output required : count of pair is 6

Comment: @kapiljain O(n) in my answer!

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera - the question was if this is the correct answer to the original question, not if that's what the implementation currently does. Only kapil can answer my question (which he did with his 1,1,1,1 example).

Comment: What does "count the all the possible pair from left to right in array" mean?  -1 for being strikingly unclear.

Answer (score 5):

Solution in O(n):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 1, 5, 23, 2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 8, 12, 3 };
    int count = 0;
    Map<Integer, Integer> elements = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        Integer e = elements.get(numbers[i]);
        if (e == null){
            e = 0;
        }
        count += e;
        elements.put(numbers[i], e+1);

    }
    System.out.println("count: "+count);
}
```

Comment: Printing `count`, while it makes sense to me, is not what OP wants. They want `count` choose 2; `(!count - !2)/(!2)`, so `[1,1,1,1]` produces `count` of `4`, and number of pairs as `(4*3*2*1 - 2*1)/(2*1)` = `(4*3)/(2)` = `12/2` = `6` pairs.

Comment: @AndyG Sorry, but I'm losing something, who is OP? can you explain this?: *They want count choose 2*, really I don't understand

Comment: @AndyG and my algorithm count 6, and Kapil jain said: *input :(1,1,1,1) output required : count of pair is 6* where is the problem?

Comment: My apologies, it produces the correct output. OP = Original Poster (the person who posted the question)

Answer (score 1):

For `[1, 1, 1, 1]` you expect `6`. In that case we are looking for all pairs `{{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}` which is the same as `6 * (6 - 1) / 2`. Note that this is the same as combinations of 6 elements taken 2 at a time. Some python code follows:

```
def dupes(arr):
   numdict = dict()
   for idx in arr:
      numdict[idx] = numdict.get(idx, 0) + 1
   count = 0
   for key, val in numdict.items():
      if val > 1:
         count = count+val*(val-1)//2 # The // 2 means divide by 2 and ignore decimal part
   return count

>>> dupes([1, 1, 1, 1])
6

>>> dupes([1, 5, 23, 2, 1, 6, 3, 1, 8, 12, 3])
4
```

A dict in python is equivalent to a hashmap in Java.